# jQuery mobile subpage (data-role='page') not as a direct child of body

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my case, i am loading different subpages from the server in runtime and those have containers (divs) doing these loadings.
The container divs then hold the subpages (divs with data-role='page') within a div.

Apparently the navigation is not working if the subpage-divs are not direct children of the body.

Am i mistaken? Is there a solution for this?

```
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div class="container">
    <div data-role="page" id="bar">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Bar</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">   
            <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my ID is beeing clicked.</p>      
            <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</div>

<!-- Start of second page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a plugin to do this?

Because Jquery Mobile by default only loads the contents of the FIRST div-data-role-page via Ajax. Unless it's your first page, which should be loaded completely. Everything else (head, scripts, your container.class will not be loaded.

See known limiatatons [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) in the docs.

To workaround, you could use the [JQM subpage plugin](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) or [JQM multiview plugin](https://github.com/frequent/multiview) (which is still in the works).

Both allow you to load subpages or nested pages inside a wrapping JQM page. It needs to be like this, because if you put your additional pages outside of the "wrapper" JQM page, JQM Ajax will not load them.

**EDIT:**
based on the comments below:

If you use multiview you could structure your page like this, ahtough this wraps ALL pages in your container class. Is this possible?

```
 <div data-role="page" data-wrapper="true" id="your_wrapper_page" class="CONTAINER">
    <div data-role="header">
       <p>global header acrolls all pages</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" data-id="main" data-panel="main" data-hash="history">
        <div data-role="page" id="main_first" data-show="first">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
                <h1>First Page LOCAL HEADER</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="yellow">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <p>first page local footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="main_second">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Second Page LOCAL HEADER</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="brown">
                <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <p>second page local footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <p>global footer acrolls all pages</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could use a popover-panel, which you can NEST inside the wrapper page, AFTER the content section, but would have to force to override some stuff inside multiview to make the popover/popup be fullscreen.

Please note, I'm still working on getting panel transitions to align with JQM 1.1. So needs some time.

Other than that, you would have to come up with your own solution, because I think JQM is not made to work like this.

Question is, if you can work without the .container?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The loading of the subpages occur independent of jQuery-mobile's AJAX calls. The only problem i face is in fact the resulting situation as in my example code that the loadad subpages must be in a container div avoiding jquery mobile to navigate to them via jQuery.mobile.changePage('#[id]'). If i could find a working workaround for this call:
jQuery.mobile.changePage("#bar")
i would be more then pleased :)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? You want to have a page, that is NOT loadable?

Comment: No. In the example above i want the call jQuery.mobile.changePage("#bar") to make the page switch to the subpage 'bar'. Which is not happening because of the div "#bar" being nested in the div ".container".

Comment: Ok, regular page, but you are forced to keep it inside div.container?